# xml Class to substitute ini files

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am learning Windows Forms in C#.NET 2008 and i want to build a class to work with SIMPLE xml files (config file like INI files), but i just need a simple class (open, getvalue, setvalue, creategroup, save and close functions), to substitute of ini files.

I already did something and it is working but I am having trouble when I need to create different groups, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CONFIG>
  <General>
    <Field1>192.168.0.2</Field1>
  </General>
  <Data>
    <Field1>Joseph</Field1>
    <Field2>Locked</Field2>
  </Data>
</CONFIG>
```

how can i specify that i want to read the field1 of [data] group?  note that i have same field name in both groups (Field1)!

I am using System.Linq, something like this:

To open document:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(FilePath);
```

To save document:

```
xmlDoc.Save(FilePath);
```

To get value:

```
public string getValue(string Field)
{
    string result = "";
    try
    {
        XmlNodeList xmlComum = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName(Field);
        if (xmlComum.Item(0) == null)
            result = "";
        else
            result = xmlComum.Item(0).InnerText;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "";
    }
    return result;
}
```

To set value:

```
public void setValue(string Group, string Field, string FieldValue)
{
    try
    {
        XmlNodeList xmlComum = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName(Field);
        if (xmlComum.Item(0) == null)
        {
            xmlComum = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName(Group);
            if (xmlComum.Item(0) == null)
            {
                // create group
                createGroup(Group);
                xmlComum = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName(Group);
            }
            XmlElement xmlE = xmlDoc.CreateElement(Field);
            XmlText xmlT = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(FieldValue);
            xmlE.AppendChild(xmlT);
            xmlComum.Item(0).AppendChild(xmlE);
        }
        else
        {
            // item already exists, just change its value
            xmlComum.Item(0).InnerText = Value;
        }
        xmlDoc.Save(FilePath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

The CreateGroup code:

```
public void createGroup(string Group)
{
    try
    {
        XmlElement xmlComum = xmlDoc.CreateElement(Group);
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlComum);
        xmlDoc.Save(FilePath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, you're not using System.Linq, you're using the old XmlDocument class. Second, get rid of those try/catch blocks, you're just eating exceptions that could be telling you what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Though you may be "using" System.Linq in your project, you are not using the so-called "Linq-to-XML" classes.  Which make things about 5 times easier, even you're not using LINQ on them!  Use the **System.Linq.XML** namesspace, to have access to these new xml classes (XDocument, XElement, etc.)

```
    XDocument XDoc = XDocument.Load("ThePath") 
    String Field1 = (String)XDoc.Root.Element("Data").Element("Field1")
```

- [Pretty good tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/net30/article.php/c13715).
- [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx).
- Good DNR TV vid-casts [here](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=80)/[here](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=81) and [here](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=147).
- A [great book on Linq](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988169) in general, and Linq-to-XML in particular
  [image: lINQ IN ACTION]

Comment: You are right, Linq is easier, you save my life!   thank you all!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the XML file as an actual repository of configuration data (just like we used to use .INI files for, back in the mists of time) then `System.Configuration` is your friend, as it handles reading and writing to `App.Config`, which is an XML file designed just for this.

Here's some detail and examples: [System.Configuration](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/DotNet/article.php/c7987/)

Of course, if you're writing a generic interface to XML files, `System.Linq.XML` is the right way to go.